# Constructing a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ of dimension $r(n-r)$ - how?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $n ∈ N$ and $1 ≤ r ≤ n$. Denote the collection of all $r$ dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{F}^n$ by $\mathcal{G}_r$, i.e. $\mathcal{G}_r = \{A: A\leq \mathbb{F}^n,dim(A)=r\}$. Show that, for every $W ∈ \mathcal{G}_r$, there exists $U ⊆ \mathcal{G}_r$ containing $W$ such that $U$ can be made a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ of dimension $r(n − r)$.

*Notation:* $P \leq Q$ means $P$ is a subspace of $Q$.

I really don't know where to start, and I'd appreciate any help. In particular, I don't understand how to find $U$ for a given $W$ such that $U$ can be made into the desired vector space.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where are you getting these problems?

Comment: Yeah.  Is it a graduate course, or not?

Comment: For this one, the Grassmanian comes to mind.  Plus the notation is suggestive.

Comment: I don't know much about it myself.  When I was a grad student, I asked Mark Green if there were higher dimensional anologues for the curl.  At least I think it was the curl.  I remember he said that was when you get into the Grassmanian and stuff.  Maybe we can do some googling.  It was a differential geometry course.

Comment: Presumably $r<n$ because $\mathcal G_n=\{\mathbb F^n\}$, so the only choice for $W$ and $U$ is $W=U=\mathbb F^n$, and $\mathbb F^n$ is $1$-dimensional over $\mathbb F^n$, not $0$-dimensional. Also, is it possible that we want to make $U$ into a vector space over $\mathbb F$, and not $\mathbb F^n$ (your title also says that we're looking for a space over $\mathbb F$)?

Comment: In the question $\ U\ $ is a *subset* of $\ \mathcal{G}_r\ $—that is, a *collection* of subspaces of dimension $\ r\ $, so "containing $\ W\ $" must mean  $\ W\in U\ $, not $\ W\subseteq U\ $. But in what sense is it then possible for $\ U\ $ to be "made into a vector space over $\ \mathbb{F}\ $"? (I'm presuming the  superscript $\ \,^n\ $ in "over $\ \mathbb{F}^n\ $" in the question is a typo).

Comment: That was an error - yes! I've changed $\mathbb{F}^n$ to $\mathbb{F}$ where it was necessary.

Comment: After being given the $r$-dimensional plane $W$, pick any $(n-r)$-dimensional plane $V$, so that $\mathbb{F}^n = W \oplus V$. Define $U$ as the set of $r$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{F}^n$ which intersect $V$ trivially. Clearly $W$ is a point in $U$. Now consider the set $L(W, V)$ of linear maps from $W$ to $V$. I claim that there is a bijection $L(W, V)$ to $U$, given by sending the linear map $f: W \to V$ to the image of $f’: W \to \mathbb{F}^n$, where $f’(w) = w + f(w)$. Under this bijection, the $r$-plane $W$ corresponds to the zero map.

Comment: I followed everything until you defined $L(W,V)$. Could you go into more detail? Why does the bijection exist? How does this help?

Comment: Also, there was a small typo (sorry)! We require a vector space of dimension $r(n-r)$, and not $n-r$. Could y'all check it out now?

Comment: It's definitely the Grassmanian you want, then.  At least, that's the dimension of the differentiable manifold.  It's a question of how you get a vector space.  Algebraic geometry is not an area I know much of anything about, but I gather you have an algebraic variety.  Good luck!

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine The space $L(W, V)$ is an $r(n-r)$-dimensional vector space, so it is the kind of thing the question is asking for. As for why the bijection exists: hopefully it is clear that the image of $f'$ is an $r$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{F}^n$ (follows from injectivity of $f'$). As for why it's surjective, I would first try looking at this for the case $r = 1$, where you are basically looking at projective space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't like problems like this (this is a complaint for whoever assigned this problem, not you). "Can be made" is extremely vague, especially with no hypothesis on the field $F$. If $F$ is an infinite field like $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ then all you have to do is show that $U$ can be taken to have the same cardinality as $F$, since no compatibility is asked for between the vector space structure on $U$ and any other structure present, and every finite-dimensional vector space over an infinite field has the same cardinality. And if $F$ is a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ all you have to do is show that $U$ can be taken to have cardinality $\mathbb{F}_q^{r(n-r)}$.

Of course this is not the intended meaning. But context is required to discern the intended meaning and it's unfair to the student to not be more specific about what "can be made" means. For those in the know, $r(n - r)$ is famously the dimension of the [Grassmannian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian) $\text{Gr}_r(F^n)$ parameterizing $r$-dimensional subspaces of $F^n$, and in particular it is the dimension of the (Zariski, if $F$ isn't $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) [tangent space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space) at each point $W \in \text{Gr}_r(F^n)$. So the *intended* meaning, which is hard to discern with confidence without this extra context, is about linearly parameterizing the subspaces "near $W$" by $r(n - r)$ parameters.

Here's a sketch of how that goes. Pick a basis $w_1, \dots w_r$ of $W$, and imagine deforming that basis into a basis of a new subspace $w_1', \dots w_r' \in W'$. What kind of deformations can we perform? Well, consider just modifying just a single vector, say $w_1$, into a new vector $w_1' = w_1 + v_1$. What can $v_1$ be? If $v_1$ is just an element of $\text{span}(w_1, w_2, \dots w_n)$ we get the same vector space $W$ back (unless the component of $w_1$ in $v_1$ cancels $w_1$ in which case we get a proper subspace of $W$, which has the wrong dimension). More generally, whatever $v_1$ is, as long as the component of $w_1$ in it doesn't cancel $w_1$ out, only its image in $F^n/W$ affects the value of $\text{span}(w_1', w_2, \dots w_n)$. So $v_1$ effectively takes values in $F^n/W$, or said another way, if we pick a complement $V$ so that $F^n = W \oplus V$, then we might as well restrict our attention to $v_1 \in V$. This ensures, as Joppy mentions in the comments, that $\text{span}(w_1', w_2, \dots w_n)$ intersects $V$ trivially.

Now you can repeat this argument for each of the other vectors $w_i$, choosing $v_1, \dots v_r \in V$ to modify them by; note that $\dim V = n - r$ so the set of ways to do this naturally forms a vector space $\text{Hom}(W, V)$ of dimension $r(n - r)$. Then you can take $w_i' = w_i + v_i$ to be the basis of the new subspace $W'$, which still intersects $V$ trivially. It remains to check that different choices of the $v_i$ produce genuinely different subspaces. Once you do, you can take $U$ to be the set of all subspaces obtained in this way.

Comment: We pick $r$ vectors labeled from $v_1$ to $v_r$ - how do we conclude that the set of ways of doing this naturally forms a vector space of dimension $r(n-r)$? Could you elaborate more on how you arrived at this, and what you mean by $\text{Hom}(W,V)$?

Comment: Also, why did we take $w'_i = w_i + v_i$? I thought the idea was to replace $w_i$ by $v_i$ altogether, I wonder why that isn't right. In addition, why not $w'_i = w_i + \alpha v_i$?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine: more explicitly the set of ways to pick $r$ vectors from $V$ is $V^r$, but since the $r$ vectors here are being labeled by a basis of $W$ what we are doing invariantly is picking a linear map $W \to V$. $\text{Hom}(W, V)$ is notation for this space of linear maps, which is itself a vector space of dimension $(\dim W)(\dim V) = r(n - r)$. Picking $w_i' = w_i + v_i$ guarantees that the vectors remain linearly independent (because they're linearly independent $\bmod V$), and corresponds intuitively to picking a "nearby" subspace if the $v_i$ are small.

Comment: And there's no need for an $\alpha$ term, we're allowing arbitrary vectors in $V$ so we can just scale them up by $\alpha$ if we want to.

Comment: Makes sense. What do you mean by "they are linearly independent mod $V$"?

Comment: Also, I do understand that we're constructing a new space $W'$ using $W, V$ such that $W \oplus V = \mathbb{F}^n$, but how does this relate to - "there exists $U ⊆ \mathcal{G}_r$ containing $W$ such that $U$ can be made a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ of dimension $r(n − r)$."? What is $U$ in this case? $V \in \mathcal{G}_{n-r}$, so not that for sure?

Comment: By linearly independent mod $V$, do you mean that if $\sum_i \alpha_i(w_i + v_i) \in V$, then $\alpha_i = 0$ because $w_i \notin V$ (so all coefficients must be zero)? Well, how does this imply linear independence in general? I haven't studied the notion of "linear independence mod subspace" earlier.

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine: hmm, thanks for asking questions, you helped me realize I didn't understand this construction as well as I thought. Joppy's comment about the resulting subspaces intersecting $V$ trivially turns out to be crucial. $U$ is the set of all subspaces that are produced by this construction. Linearly independent $\bmod V$ means the thing you said, it's equivalent to linear independence in the quotient space $F^n/V$, and it implies linear independence because any linear dependence in $F^n$ projects to a linear dependence in $F^n/V$ (then take the contrapositive of this).